# undefined symbol: clock_gettime with tensorflow on ubuntu14.04

Tags: python, ubuntu, tensorflow

I have installed tensorflow from source with bazel. But when I import tensorflow in python,the error happens.

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/zjuese/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "/home/zjuese/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.client.client_lib import *
  File "/home/zjuese/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/client_lib.py", line 39, in <module> 
    from tensorflow.python.client.session import InteractiveSession
  File "/home/zjuese/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 16, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow as tf_session
  File "/home/zjuese/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 26, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()
  File "/home/zjuese/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 22, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: /home/zjuese/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so: undefined symbol: clock_gettime
```

How can I fix it now?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try adding the `rt` library during the linking step, like in this diff:

```
--- a/tensorflow/tensorflow.bzl
+++ b/tensorflow/tensorflow.bzl
@@ -284,7 +284,7 @@ _py_wrap_cc = rule(attrs={

 def tf_extension_linkopts():
-  return []  # No extension link opts
+  return ["-lrt"]
```

See also this [github issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/121).

Comment: Thanks a lot.I rebuild tewnsorflow with the modified tensorflow.bzl .And now I can import tensorflow without any error.

Comment: plus one for linking github issue

Comment: can we specify it via --linkopt to avoid modifying the file?